# Firebase signs out user after signing in

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, web, firebase-authentication

I have the problem that my firebase hosting website has an `/account` route which dynamically loads a content page, depending on if the user is signed-in or not.
For detecting the users state, I am using firebase auth's `onAuthStateChange` callback:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    console.log("authstate changed:"+user);
    let pagereq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (user) {
        console.log(user.email);
        user.getIdTokenResult(true).then((idtokenres) => {
            if(idtokenres.claims.admin){
                console.log("user is admin");
            }
        });
        pagereq.open("GET","./account-management/management.html",true);
        logout.addEventListener("click",handleLogout());
    } else {
        logout.parentNode.removeChild(logout);
        pagereq.open("GET","./account-management/login/login-page.html",true);
    }
}
```

When the user is signed in a dynamically loaded login form appears and enables a sign in with an email and a password. The user now enters his credentials and hits 'sign in'. The content area reloads due to the callback and shows a console page.
Here comes the problem. When the user signs in, `onAuthStateChanged` is called twice: first sucessful with the exact `user`-Object and second with `user = null`.
The console page dynamically loads a script after the console page itself is loaded. In the script, there also is an `onAuthStateChanged` function which will be called normally. Here, the callback is called only once and `user` also is null. ***Why is that and how can I workaround this problem?***
Ican not detect why the `user`-Object null at the second call and also null in the dynamically loaded script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `()` on your `handleLogout`
So it would be like `logout.addEventListener(‘click’, handleLogout)`